# Objective-C + Swift with CoreData - Can not assign value type of 'EntityName' to type 'EntityName!'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

**SENARIO**

I am working on a project that I am merging Swift 3 into an Objective-C project. The project is using CoreData and in my Objective-C `AppDelegate` I declare a type of my "EntityName" and and trying to assign in my Swift 3 class and am getting build error "can not assign type of 'EntityName' to type 'EntityName!'".

---

**CODE**

*AppDelegate.h*

```
// Declaration
@property (strong, nonatomic) EntityName * entity;
```

*Swift Class*

```
// Array Property
var entityList = [EntityName]()

...

// Assignment
let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.entity = self.entityList[indexPath.row] // throws error
```

---

**ERROR**

```
can not assign type of 'EntityName' to type 'EntityName!'
```

---

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

1)

```
appDelegate.entity = self.entityList[indexPath.row] as EntityName! // throws error
```

**ERROR**

```
can not assign type of 'EntityName!' to type 'EntityName!'
```

2)

```
appDelegate.entity = self.entityList[indexPath.row] as EntityName? // throws error
```

**ERROR**

```
can not assign type of 'EntityName?' to type 'EntityName!'
```

---

**QUESTION**

How do I rectify this and get on with my day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I found the fix to this issue. In my case I had to follow these steps:

**1)** navigate to and select the CoreData model...

`AppName.xcdatamodeld`

**2)** on the right side, view the file inspector...

[image]

**3)** in **code generation** section, choose Objective-C as language...

[image]

---

My `.xcdatamodeld` file code generation was set to Swift. I believe the old adage, "it's easier for Swift to conform to Objective-C than Objective-C to Swift" holds true here.